# chaining param scopes from seperate forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i could create an advanced search form where users can be filtered `by photos_count` and by `countryname` in the same form.

but what if i want to setup my app so that users can first be filtered by_photos_count and then also be filtered by countryname after that (two separate forms that pass params to the query string with a get request)?

**UsersController**

```
def index
   @users = User.all.paginate(page: params[:page])
   @users = User.countryname(params[:country]).paginate(page: params[:page]) if params[:country].present?
   @users = User.by_photos_count.paginate(page: params[:page]) if params[:photos_count].present?
end
```

currently, the forms do not acknowledge if there already params passed in the query string.

**Edit:** This is how I want the forms to work:

> example.com/users

user selects a country:

```
<%= form_tag users_path, method: :get, class: 'country' do %>
```

> example.com/users?country='US'

user then sorts by photos_count

> example.com/users?country='US'&photos_count=true

My problem is that my params are not currently being chained. it goes from example.com/users?country='US' to example.com/users?photos_count=true

Comment: so let me see if I understand: you want a pair of separate http get requests to pass in query filter information to be run in the same query? I mean, you want to send a request for part of the filter and send another request for the other part and THEN execute the query and return results?

Comment: please see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a reasonably small amount of possible parameters, you can pass on the existing parameters in the form as hidden fields.

```
<%= form_tag users_path, method: :get, class: 'country' do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :photos_count, params[:photos_count] if params[:photos_count].present? %>
...
```

Comment: so if there are several possible parameters should we create a single advanced form that is updated with ajax to continually filter results upon new parameters added... like you would see on a retail website?

Comment: That's one way to do it. In this case however, you could probably just try incorporating all the filter options in one form.